# xmlsuite setPreserveOrder () parameter type

Tags: xml, testng

I am building the TestNG xml file for parallel test execution pro programatically from the main JAVA class using the XmlSuite class. The javadoc for XmlSuite indicates that the setPreserveOrder() method takes a String as parameter (values= "true" | "false").

The code is:

```
XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
suite.setName("Parallel Mobile Tests");
suite.setParallel(ParallelMode.TESTS);
suite.setThreadCount(2);

suite.setPreserveOrder("true");
suite.setConfigFailurePolicy("skip");
```

However, when I examine the resultant xml file, the *preserve-order='true'* and *configfailurepolicy='skip'* are not added to the list of parameters for the suite statement.  It is

```
<suite thread-count="2" name="Parallel Mobile Tests" parallel="tests">
```

Some of the examples shown on the internet show that setPreserveOrder() takes a boolean value for parameter.

I'm confused.....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, setPreserveOrder is Boolean now, string type Deprecated. check javadoc here https://jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master/javadoc/org/testng/xml/XmlSuite.html We have to use like

```
  suite.setPreserveOrder(true);
```

and i hope need to use like this for continue, you can use skip also

```
  suite.setConfigFailurePolicy(FailurePolicy.CONTINUE);
```

Comment: Thanks, Murali.  When i change to use Boolean, a syntax error is generated:  The method setPreserveOrder(String) in the type XmlSuite is not applicable for the arguments (Boolean)

Comment: The testNG version that I'm using is 6.14.9.291792161500.  My Eclipse says that this version is the latest (aka does not find any updates).

Comment: Please remove previous imports and try freshly

Comment: I just did that but did not have any luck :(

Comment: I  re-specified the build path libraries and this time, the code sees the new definition of setPreserveOrder( ) to take boolean argument.  However, the resulting XML file does not contain that parameter (preserve-order="true")